# Background Image Does Not Cover On Mobile

Tags: html, css

I have a background image on my homepage that correctly covers the entirety of the screen. However, on mobile, the image does not resize to fit properly. It instead only shows a portion of the image. The css is below:

```
#hero {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  overflow: auto;
  background: url("./hero.webp") no-repeat center center fixed; 
  background-size: cover;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #hero {
    height: 100vh;
  }
}
```

Here is a link to the homepage. If you resize the browser to mimic a mobile screen you will see what I am talking about:

https://stormy-temple-25830.herokuapp.com/#/

Comment: That's because you have the `#hero` container height set to `50vh` (50% of the viewable height) on mobile. That being said, using `background-size:contain;` is **always** going to cause only a portion of the image to be visible(unless the browser window is the same ratio as the image) because it stretches the image to fill the height and width of the container.

Comment: I tried putting the hero inside of a container where the height was always 100% and then adjusting the height of the hero inside to 50vh but I had the same problem.

Comment: If you restrain the hero element or any containing element of the hero element to `50vh` it's only going to cover 50% of the height of the screen.

Comment: @APAD1 I think you mean `background-size: cover;` not `contain`. Contain always shows the whole image and cover always fills the whole area

Comment: @zgood Yep, that's what I meant. Too late to edit now, thanks!

Comment: So is there any way to have the hero div only take up half the screen but still have the image fully covering the background?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by removing 'no-repeat center center fixed' from my background-image property. Here's the updated css:

```
#hero {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  overflow: auto;
  background: url("./hero.webp"); 
  background-size: cover;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #hero {
    height: 100vh;
  }
}
```